# Using the first pane's path as default when opening a new pane in tmux?

Tags: tmux

```
+--------+-----+
|        |  1  |
|   0    |-----+
|        |  2  |
+--------+-----+
```

When opening pane 2 from pane 1, I hope pane 2's current path is same as pane 0 ? how to do that ?

I custom some hotkey in tmux config file to achieve it, but don't work it out.

Comment: I got bored halfway through. You can get the cwd of pane 0 with `tmux display -p -F "#{pane_current_path}" -t0` and you can set what the new pane's directory will be with `split-window -h -c "/target/path/". I don't know how to combine them, since tmux doesn't seem to want to read the bash variable.

Comment: @jeremysprofile, really appreciate your reply. tmux `send-keys` is the magic, I finally work it out though it's ugly. `bind b split-window -v \; send-keys -l 'cmd (tmux display -p -F "#{pane_current_path}" -t0)/build' \; send-keys 'C-m' 'C-l'` in my fish shell, I could hit `<Prefix>b` to the job.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to change the current pane's directory based on the first pane.

**In fish shell**

```
bind b split-window -v \; \
  send-keys -l 'cd (tmux display -p -F "#{pane_current_path}" -t0)/build' \; \
  send-keys 'C-m' 'C-l'
```